# Is this correct grammatically?

Tags: grammar, american-english

"You could have flewn on coming Sunday"

I mean to say that you could have taken the flight on Sunday

Comment: No it’s not grammatical and “*flewn*” isn’t a word.

Answer (score 1):

[Past participle of `fly`](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/fly.html) is **`flown`** not `flewn`.
So your sentence should be

> You could have flown on the coming Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, *flewn* is not a word. **Flown** is the correct form (past participle) of it here.

> "You could have flown on the coming Sunday"

Answer (score 1):

To be precise: "You could have flown Sunday."

"You could have flown this Sunday."

Depending on the context and what's previously understood.

Comment: In British English, "on Sunday" would be much more likely than just "Sunday". But "this Sunday" would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not correct at all.

*You could have flown on Sunday* would mean you could have taken the flight on Sunday; not just any but either next or last Sunday, depending on context.

*You could have flown on* the *Sunday* would mean you could have taken the flight on the Sunday of the relevant week, which at the time of the conversation is in the past.

*You could have flown on the coming Sunday* only fits a complicated set of conditional circumstances.

*You could have flown* clearly implies some relevant time has already passed. Either Sunday itself, or the possibility of flying on Sunday, is now in the past.

*This coming Sunday* is only ever used from Monday to Friday to refer to the Sunday next following the conversation. By Saturday, that Sunday becomes tomorrow.

*The coming Sunday* is only ever used of the future or the past, and always beyond the Sunday immediately following or preceding the conversation.

*You could have flown on* the *coming Sunday* could only be used when so many more Sundays had passed that the actual date had become moot.

*You could have flown on* this *coming Sunday* could only be used between Monday and Friday to refer to the Sunday immediately following the conversation, and after the possibility of flying that day had passed.